# Comparing values in an array and calculating the difference in ranges Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, compare, subtraction

I am trying to code a function that checks if a value has went down more than 100 between a range of values for `val` `103.0, 58.8, 35, -47` the values went from 103 to -47 which is -150 also `58.8, 35, -47` the values went from 58 to -47 that is a decrease of -105. So those are 2 of the cases were there was a drop from an initial value to a value equivalent to or over -100. It checks if there was a drop by -100 for each value in the array till the end of the array. So if it took the number `7.4` then it would check for the rest of the array being `1180.9, 0.6, 103.0, 58.8, 35, -47, 47.2, 78.1, 37.8` and if the value is `1180.9` then it would check the values `0.6, 103.0, 58.8, 35, -47, 47.2, 78.1, 37.8`. how would I be able to do that with numpy.

```
import numpy as np 

val = np.array([7.4, 1180.9, 0.6, 103.0, 58.8, 35, -47, 47.2, 78.1, 37.8])
val2 = np.array([46.5, 55.7, 7.0, 19.6, 7.6, 36.5, 34.7, 101.9, 179.7, 85.5])
val3 = np.array([120, 20, -80, -5.5])

differences = 100

def run(values):
    minimums = np.subtract.accumulate(values)
    print(f'Number it has been below or equal to {differences} is {values}')
    return minimums
    
print(run(val))
print(run(val2))
print(run(val3))
```

Expected Output:

```
Number it has been below or equal to -100 is 3
Number it has been below or equal to -100 is 0
Number it has been below or equal to -100 is 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([7.4, 1180.9, 0.6, 103.0, 58.8, 35, -47, 47.2, 78.1, 37.8]) 
val2 = np.array([46.5, 55.7, 7.0, 19.6, 7.6, 36.5, 34.7, 101.9, 179.7, 85.5]) 
val3 = np.array([120, 20, -80, -5.5]) 

def run( arr, limit ): 
    row_mins = np.triu( arr[None, : ] - arr[ :, None ] ).min(axis = 1 ) 
    return np.count_nonzero( row_mins <= -limit )
```

Expanded:

```
def run( arr, limit ):
    # Uncomment the print statements to see what is happening.
    temp = arr[None, : ] - arr[ :, None ]  # difference of each element all elements
    # print( temp )
    temp1 = np.triu( temp )  # Keep the upper triangle, set lower to zero
    # print( temp1 )
    row_mins = temp1.min( axis = 1 )   # Minimum for each row
    # print( row_mins )
    return np.count_nonzero( row_mins <= -limit ) # Count how many row_mins are <= limit
```

Results:

```
run(val, 100)   # 3
run(val2, 100)  # 0
run(val3, 100)  # 2
```

Comment: Thank you it works I tried to do the opposite where instead of a drawdown of 100 looked for an upside of 100. But it is not really working I tried the following code:   `row_mins = np.triu( arr[None, : ] + arr[ :, None ] ).min(axis = 1 ) 
 return np.count_nonzero(row_mins >= limit )`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure  what you 're trying to do but I think you still want differences, not the sum and probably need max, not min.  So `row_maxs = np.triu( arr[None, : ] - arr[ :, None ] ).max(axis = 1 )`.  Does that work?